# Discord.Net - Get A User's Bio/About Me

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am trying to find a method or way to get a user's bio that joins my server and checks it to make sure it is appropriate but have found absolutely nothing through the docs or on Google. If there is a method that someone can kindly show me that would be fantastic thank you.

Heres What I have so far

```
            string[] swearWords = { "bad", "word" };
            var user = Context.User;
            string bio = ; //Code Here

            if (swearWords.All(bio.Contains))
            {
                //ignore
            }
```

Comment: I don't think you can. https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/3095

Comment: Bots in general have typically been restricted from accessing profile and bio information in the API

Comment: There is no official way stated in discord's developer documentation at the moment.

Ps: `if (swearWords.Any(swearWord => bio.Contains(swearWord)))`